# how can i use every devices screen on imageview.setontouchlistener with get x y positions?

Tags: android, imageview

This positions are works only 480x800 screens devices. But don't right works 1024x600 device. How can i fix it?

```
       sinif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSinif);
    sinif.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"x= " +x + " y= " +y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if ((610 < event.getX() && event.getX() < 703)
                    && (11 < event.getY() && event.getY() < 128)
                    && deger == 0) {
                // i want run any method in there. for example:
                myAnimation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                sinif.setEnabled(false);
                sinif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                sorulist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text1.setOnClickListener(dinle);
                text2.setOnClickListener(dinle);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: The && event.gets in your if don't do anything, I would remove all but the deger == 0 part of your if unless you have you want to limit your buttons to only being set within small regions

Comment: use getImageMatrix() and invert() it in order to mapPoints()

Comment: how can i use? Do you have example? @pskink

Comment: just get the Matrix, invert() it and call mapPoints() on inverted Matrix

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing value of touch X and Y with hard coded values say 601,703,11,128. But as android specification pixel value are device dependent so you need to convert it to device dependent size.

```
if ((convertSizeToDeviceDependent(610) < event.getX() && event.getX() < convertSizeToDeviceDependent(703))
                && (convertSizeToDeviceDependent(11) < event.getY() && event.getY() < convertSizeToDeviceDependent(128)) && deger == 0) {
            // i want run any method in there. for example:
            myAnimation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            sinif.setEnabled(false);
            sinif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            sorulist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text1.setOnClickListener(dinle);
            text2.setOnClickListener(dinle);
        }
```

**Put This Method in your Activity**

```
public int convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        return ((dm.densityDpi * value) / 160);
    }
```

Comment: it's not working on high pixels devices. i guess 160 is dpi. Which devices have 160dpi, it works. @Biraj Zalavadia

Comment: @bkm use mapPoints as  wrote in my comment